# What is Microsoft Kernel Debug Network Adapter?

Tags: windows-8

What is the `Microsoft Kernel Debug Network Adapter`? What purposes does it serve? Where does it come from?

It shows up under `Network adapters` in `Device Manager`. I have disabled it.

[image]

Comment: Related: [What is Microsoft Kernel Debug Network Adapter?](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_8-networking/what-is-microsoft-kernel-debug-network-adapter/f72b8408-e4f7-4593-9e18-8cbb3e38a5ad)

Comment: I found that, but it didn't answer my questions

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For remote kernel debugging, you need a kernel module to allow it. This is that module.

> In the Previous editions of Microsoft® Windows Operating Systems Kernel Debugging was performed through Serial Cable, USB and 1394(Firewire). In these methods we had several challenges like serial connectivity being slow; USB requiring special hardware which may not be cost effective and 1394 port being rarely available on all the servers. These challenges can be overcome by Kernel Debugging over network.

[Kernel Debugging Over Network in Windows Server 2012](http://en.community.dell.com/techcenter/os-applications/w/wiki/3901.kernel-debugging-over-network-in-windows-server-2012.aspx)

Supposedly, the device is added when you activate kernel debugging like so:

```
bcdedit /debug on
```

It can be removed through:

```
bcdedit /debug off
```

Comment: that's weird, I have never activated it myself. What is "remote kernel debugging" exactly?

Comment: @Chin: It's when you want to [debug](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Debugging) Windows itself. This can be quite complicated because to debug, you may want to *pause* execution of the program you're debugging. If you pause the kernel, you'll find you'll have a hard time using the computer :) This is why you would want to debug the kernel from *another* workstation. The linked article goes into a bit more detail about the process.

Comment: thanks. I guess disabling it is a good idea then. I don't want anyone to debug my computer remotely

Comment: can I even uninstall it?

Comment: @Chin: Apparently, `bcdedit /debug off` should work. Otherwise uninstalling the device through Device Manager seems to be another option. Although I have no experience trying this.